# thread 1: exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0) error

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on this recorder project and this code is written in swift 2.0 and it is giving this issue!
I have seem similar title post but is not related to the issue I am having

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlaySoundViewController: UIViewController {

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
var receivedAudio: AudioRecorded!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.




    do{

      let     audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: receivedAudio.filePathUrl) --> ***The error happens here***

           audioPlayer.enableRate = true
    }catch let ErrorType {

         NSLog("Could not create AVAudioPlayer: \(ErrorType)")
    }
```

}

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

@IBAction func playFastSound(sender: AnyObject) {
    audioPlayer.stop()
    audioPlayer.play()
    audioPlayer.rate = 2.0



}

@IBAction func playSlowSound(sender: AnyObject)
{
    audioPlayer.stop()
    audioPlayer.play()
    audioPlayer.rate = 0.5

}


@IBAction func stopPlaying(sender: AnyObject) {

    audioPlayer.stop()

}
/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Comment: can you post the url returned for "receivedAudio.filePathUrl"

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be the use of `try!` during allocation.

As [HWS puts it](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch) -

> There's one more thing to discuss, which is what to do if you know a call simply can't fail, for whatever reason. Now, clearly this is a decision you need to make on a case-by-case basic, but if you know there's absolutely no way a method call might fail, or if it did fail then your code was so fundamentally broken that you might as well crash, you can use try! to signal this to Swift.

So that's not what you want, probably. 
For error handling, you'd typically use `try` (without the `!`).

```
    do {
        let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: receivedAudio.filePathUrl)
        // Do stuff with audio player
    }
    catch let error {
        NSLog("Could not create AVAudioPlayer: \(error)")
    }
```

Now that doesn't explain why the audio player isn't being created. Most likely the URL is invalid, the file it points to doesn't exist, or it's encoded in something AVAudioPlayer can't read. Typically you'll want a standard file format like mp3, mp4, etc.

Comment: Initializer for conditional binder must have Option type, not 'AVAudioPlayer' Call can trow, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Comment: I did what you told and still the same error. Thanks for your help